# Insert new records in to mysql table using nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, arrays, node.js

I have a table call `APIpages` and it contains `id,page_id,page_name`. It already contains some records.
Also I have an Array, it contains page details.

What I want to do with my function is:
check if pages are already inserted, if not insert that row into table.

**page array**

```
 var API_pages=  [{
        "name": "ABC",
        "id": 1111
     },
    {
        "name": "DEF",
        "id": 2222
    },
    {
        "name": "GHI",
        "id": 3333
    }];
```

**APIpages table**

```
+---+------------+-------------+
| id| page_id    | page_name   |
+---+------------+-------------+
| 1 | 2222       | DEF         |
|   |            |             |
|   |            |             |
+---+------------+-------------+
```

**nodejs function**

```
    exports.apiPages = (req, res) => {

    var data = {
        data: API_pages
      };

     for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {

        var query = 'SELECT id FROM APIpages WHERE page_id="' + data.data[i].id + '"';

        var a = sequelize.query(query, {
          type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT
        }).then(function (results) {
          console.log("result=====>", JSON.stringify(results));
        });
    }

  var insertpage = function () {
    APIpages.create({
      page_id: data.data[i].id,
      page_name: data.data[i].name,

    }).then(
      function (ok) {
        response.success(res, data);
        return;
      },
      function (err) {
        console.log(err);
        response.fail(res, response.message.server_error);
        return;
      }
    );

  }
    };
```

This is my code. First I want to search in table with array records, if there is a new record in array, I want to insert it in to table.
`console.log` showing `result=====>[{"id":1}] result=====>[],result=====>[]`.
My problem is, how can I call `insertpage` when new record comes?

Comment: So what's the problem with the code?

Comment: when new record comes how can i insert (call insertpage)?